# NPM ENOENT when i try to create new react app

Tags: reactjs

I`m trying to create react app and got this output:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT  
npm ERR! syscall lstat  
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm  
npm ERR! errno -4058  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'  
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-14T15_02_48_983Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I fix this problem?

I tried to reinstall node.js and change location of my folder. Also I checked if node.js installed succesfully by entering `node -v` and `npm -v`. It works right.

Comment: Hi! I would recommend putting the error text from the image inside of a code block and potentially removing the image. (It doesn't really matter to me but some people here may get angry lol)